# How to change the folder location in skimage.io.imsave?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am using skimage for image processing. First I read the image, change that to grayscale and save the image in another location. My code doesn't work when I try to save it in another location. Can anyone help?

`

```
    import skimage.io
    from skimage.color import rgb2gray

    def gray_image(image_path=None):
       print("Running on {}".format(args.image)
       image=skimage.io.imread(args.image)
       graycale=rgb2gray(image)
       file_name="gray_{:%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}.png".format("/new_path/", datetime.datetime.now())
       skimage.io.imsave(filename, grayscale)


    gray_image(image_path="/path/to/file")
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you mean

```py
file_name="/new_path/gray_{:%Y%m%dT%H%M%S}.png".format(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: No.. let's say I am taking the inputs from "test" folder in D drive and I want to save the new greyscale image to "results" folder in the same drive. So how to do that?

Comment: I still don't see the problem? replace "new_path" with "/d/results/[whateverfilenameyouwant]"?

Comment: Sorry you are right. I did not understand it first. I tried your suggestion and its working now. Thank you for your valuable time.